# how to know when an activity date has passed - django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

so i'm still on my todo list and i want to know when an activity has passed so as to flag it as expired.

my views.py

```
def progress(request):
    activities = ToDo.objects.all()
    today = timezone.localtime(timezone.now())
    context = {
        'activities' : activities,
        'today' : today, 
    }
    return render(request, 'percent.html', context)
```

in my templates i have it as:

```
 {% for activity in activities %}
    {% if activity.end.date < today.date %}
    {{activity}} <br>
    {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
```

i'm going to add my models.py for referencing

```
class ToDo(models.Model):
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    todo = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    description = models.TextField(max_length=200, blank=True)
    created = models.DateField(auto_now=True)
    end = models.DateField()
    start = models.DateField()
    completed = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.owner} - {self.todo}'
```

or would it be easier to add an expired boolean field to my models? i'm so confused

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use any scheduler, you can get expired items in another request, using ORM Manager:

```
from django.db import models


class ToDoManager(models.Manager):
    def active(self):
        return self.excude(end__lt=today().date)

    def expired(self):
        return self.filter(end__lt=today().date)


class ToDo(models.Model):
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    todo = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    description = models.TextField(max_length=200, blank=True)
    created = models.DateField(auto_now=True)
    end = models.DateField()
    start = models.DateField()
    completed = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    
    objects = ToDoManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.owner} - {self.todo}'
```

And in your view you'll get them in a different requests:

```
ToDo.objects.active()
ToDo.objects.expired()
```

Or you can change manager with setting expired flag and saving results when requesting data from db

Answer (score 0):

**Note: You need to use [Celery Beat](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/userguide/periodic-tasks.html) as a scheduler.**

```
import datetime

def expired_activity():
    today = datetime.date.today()
    expired_activity = ToDo.objects.filter(end=today)
    if expired_activity:
            expired_activity.update(completed=True)
```